# Dynamically loading a large jQuery selectable/sortable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I'm trying to set up a list element (to be used in a form) that uses both jQuery Sortable and Selectable plugins, that uses the Sortable "connectWith" feature, and contains a large amount of elements.

I have a way to create the element I need using Sortable and Selectable, but the list takes a long time to load, freezing up the whole page until it's done (and it takes long enough that Firefox tells me "A web page is slowing down your browser"). I'm trying to figure out how I can best make the list load within the page and stop my web browser from complaining.

A long loading time for this element is fine - what I think I want to do is separately load the element in a div within the page, and ideally show a "loading" div over the that while it's loading.

Below is the code I'm using, adapted from here: https://codepen.io/kabuki/pen/NPLmWY

Javascript (using jQuery 3.3.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1):

```
$('#search_elements_included, #search_elements_available').selectable({
    cancel: '.handle, .ui-selected',
    filter: '> li'
}).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items: "> li",
    handle: 'div, .handle, .ui-selected',
    helper: function(e, item) {
        if ( ! item.hasClass('ui-selected') ) {
            item.parent().children('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
            item.addClass('ui-selected');
        }
        var selected = item.parent().children('.ui-selected').clone();
        ph = item.outerHeight() * selected.length;
        item.data('multidrag', selected).siblings('.ui-selected').remove();
        return $('<li/>').append(selected);
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
        console.log(ph);
        console.log(ui.placeholder);
        ui.placeholder.css({'height':ph});
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        var selected = ui.item.data('multidrag');
        ui.item.after(selected);
        ui.item.remove();
    }
});
```

Django template code:

```
<div id="search_dropdown">
    <ul id="search_elements_available" class="selectable connectedSortable">

        {% for one_element in search_element_options %}

            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                <div class='handle'><i class='ui-icon ui-icon-search'></i></div>
                <div class="sort-item">
                    {{ one_element.header }} ({{ one_element.field_id }})
                </div>
            </li>

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

    <ul id="search_elements_included" class="selectable connectedSortable">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div id="search_dropdown">
    <ul id="search_elements_available" class="selectable connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <div class='handle'><i class='ui-icon ui-icon-search'></i></div>
            <div class="sort-item">Element 1 (element_1_id)</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <div class='handle'><i class='ui-icon ui-icon-search'></i></div>
            <div class="sort-item">Element 2 (element_2_id)</div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <div class='handle'><i class='ui-icon ui-icon-search'></i></div>
            <div class="sort-item">Element 3 (element_3_id)</div>
        </li>        
        <! -- ... many more li elements ... -->
    </ul>

    <ul id="search_elements_included" class="selectable connectedSortable">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've looked at jQuery.load() but I don't need to load an external page, so I don't think that's what I want.

I've tried putting the javascript in a separate function that gets called on document.ready(), but this still freezes up the whole page.

I've also looked at this Lazy library for jQuery: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/ but I'm not sure whether it's possible to adapt that for something like this, or what I would need to be lazy-loading in the first place (like would I want to lazy-load each form element? Also, the form elements are being generated by Django template language so I'd have to work around that, too.)

If anyone can provide some advice on how best to load this kind of large thing in-page it would be much appreciated. Also, if the title of this post isn't appropriately describing the problem, feel free to modify it.

Thanks!

Comment: How are the `LI` generated? Dynamically or are they statically in the HTML?

Comment: They're generated via Django template code. I've updated my code to include the Django template loop that generates the list items.

Comment: I see two things that could be causing load issues, 1) Django having to create all the HTML. Onmce that is `ready` then jQuery is run to initiate Sortable for each of the many items and this will cause a lot of memory usage in the browser. If you wan tto load a portion, the you may consider AJAX, loading a few with Django and then doing an ajax call after page load to populate the list further.